# Check only visible checkboxes of a Repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using the code below to bind a `Repeater`:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptList" runat="server" OnItemCommand="rptList_ItemCommand">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr class="odd gradeX" id="trid" runat="server">
            <td data-title="Code">
                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkid" runat="server" AutoPostBack="false" />
                <asp:HiddenField ID="hiddenid" runat="server" Value='<%#Eval("Visa_Type_Id") %>'/>
            </td>
            <td class="hidden-480"><%#Container.ItemIndex+1 %></td>
            <td class="hidden-480">
                <asp:LinkButton ID="lnk1" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("Visa_Type_Id") %>'><%#Eval("Visa_Type_Name") %> </asp:LinkButton>
            </td>
            <td class="hidden-480"><%#Eval("Visa_Description") %></td>
            <td class=" " style="width: 100px;"><a href="#"><span class="label label-success">Active</span></a>&nbsp;<a href="#"><span class="label label-success">Publish</span></a></td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

The code below is to check all the checkboxes:

```
protected void chkAll_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= rptList.Items.Count - 1; i++)
    {
        CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)rptList.Items[i].FindControl("chkid");
        if (chk.Checked == true)
        {
            chk.Checked = false;
        }
        else
        {
            chk.Checked = true;
        }
    }
}
```

now by above code all the checkboxes in the `Repeater` are checked but I just want to check the ones which are displayed in paging. At the moment, if I am on page 1, using the above code, the boxes on page 2 are also checked.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

you can use jQuery instead of server side code:
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/w3gQJ/)

```
 $("#checkAll").click(function () {
     $('input:checkbox').not(this).prop('checked', this.checked);
 });
```